# Detect language and compare to list of words

Tags: python, set

The set in my code isn't working when I throw it into my code that detects language.

The code I have is meant to detect the language (which is 'de' and is properly detected), and then if the language is 'de', it will compare the words in the file to words in another file.

When I have these codes as separate codes, they both work, but when I have them together, the output is wrong.

Expected output is **{'mehr', 'Angebot'}** and actual output is **set()**

Code:

```
from langdetect import detect

f = open("4.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
read = f.read()

lang = detect(read)

#print(lang)

if lang == 'de':
    de = open("positive_words_de.txt")

    words1 = f.read().split()
    words2 = de.read().split()
    words = set(words1) & set(words2)
    print(words)

f.close()
de.close()
```

Here's the text on the file 4.txt

```
Re: stuttgarter-zeitung.de Bei der Bahn bekomme ich für mehr Geld mehr Service. Ich bin zuversichtlich, dass ein kleines Unternehmen sich um ein gutes Angebot für Ihre Kunden kümmern werden. Wir werden sehen...
```

The words in the file positive_words_de.txt is just a list of words with positive affiliation in German, two words match the words in the 4.txt file, as noted above.

Comment: Can you add the output of printing the contents of `words1` and `words2`?

Comment: What's the content of `positive_words_de.txt` ? https://github.com/socialsensor/computational-verification/blob/master/resources/files/positive-words-german.txt ?

Comment: Thanks alex, words1 is empty. The fix was rather easy, as I posted below. I will keep in mind to run more prints when my code isn't acting right!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
from langdetect import detect
with open("4.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    read = f.read().strip()

lang = detect(read)
print(lang)

if lang == 'de':
    # https://github.com/socialsensor/computational-verification/raw/master/resources/files/positive-words-german.txt
    with open("positive_words_de.txt") as de:
        de_positive = de.read()
    words1 = [x.strip().lower() for x in de.split("\n")]
    words2 = [x.strip().lower() for x in de_positive.split("\n")]
    words = set(words1) & set(words2)
    print(words)

#de
#{'bahn'}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was with this line:

```
words1 = f.read().split()
```

If I either remove `read = f.read()` or change `words1 = f.read().split()` to `words1 = read.split` the code works just fine. `words1` is an empty list when I run the original code.